# Website showing favicon for old site in Big Sur Safari tab

Tags: safari

I migrated a website to a new platform and server. However, the old favicon for the old site still remains. In other browsers (Chrome, Firefox), the new favicon shows up just fine, no problems.

I tried:

1. Clearing website cache
2. Following instructions found on web to clear Favicon/Touch Icon folder.  I could find no such beast in Big Sur.
3. Pulling up the website in private browser mode.

I think Apple has to be pulling the favicon from the cloud or something. I see no way to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed:

From "Developer" menu, click on "Empty caches."

I'm not sure why clearing caches using the traditional method of clearing caches in Safari preferences did not work.

Comment: THIS! Thank you so much! Finally! Got an icon from an old project stuck to my localhost for a year! Tried deleting Favicons Cache, and the entire website data from the Settings, Private mode, nothing changed. And this somehow worked. Wow.